# Actions may not have an undefined "type" property in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

What is this error saying? I got this error while dispatching request to the redux store.

```
Error: Actions may not have an undefined "type" property. Have you misspelled a constant?
client/src/redux/alert/alertActions.jsx:18
  15 |             variant: variant
  16 |         }
  17 |     })
> 18 |     setTimeout(()=> dispatch(actionType(REMOVE_ALERT, {id: 1})),timeout)
  19 | }
  20 |
```

Comment: it's pretty clear: your Redux action has no `type` property, or has it but it holds the value `undefined`. Have a look at what `actionType` returns - go step through your code and debug it (but feel free to come back here if you're struggling).

Comment: Yes that's exactly. I should have returned type and payload from actionType({type,payload}) but, I was returning action and payload as actionType({action,payload}). Now solved. :D :D